# How to change the Data panel properties hover over information?

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-webplayer

I am trying to find out if it's possible to customise what gets shown when I hover over any of the properties inside the Data Panel (inside the Spotfire **Analyst**). The current behaviour is to show the name of the property itself but I would like to change it so it shows a description showing what the property means.

[image: s]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [TIBCO community](https://community.tibco.com/questions/how-change-data-panel-properties-hover-over-information#node-1095846), the option to see a description upon hover over is available in Spotfire 10.3. The version I am running is 10.0.

[image]

Comment: I have not used 10.x yet but even back on 7.14 (where I am now) you can edit column properties and give it a description? Does that not work from 10.0 to 10.2?

Comment: Unfortunately, my team have access to 10.0 and 10.3 so I can't tell you for sure. However, tibco support mentioned that this feature is available in 10.3